# Apache Velocity: replace newline does not work

Tags: java, spring, newline, velocity

In my Java/Spring Web Application I'm using Velocity Template (1.7) in order to "build" a HTML mail message.

When I pass a custom object to the .vm template I can't replace the "\n" (newline) chars present with a html break `<br />`

I mean:

```
<p>$myobject.description.replace("\n","<br/>")</p>
```

not works, but If I replace another random char different from "\n" then It works.

I tried with double escape `$myobject.description.replace("\\n","<br/>")` without any success.

If the same line of code

```
myobject.description.replace("\n","<br/>");
```

is executed in my service Bean It works and every newline is correctly replaced with html break.

Can you tell what it's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use replaceAll with new line as suggest in [velocity archive answer](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/velocity-user/200703.mbox/%3C4d651da50703051045n7e7fde72i2a623bbf2e5609ff@mail.gmail.com%3E):

> As of Velocity 1.5 (and its beta releases), VTL allows line breaks
>   within string literal definitions.  This means that you would put a
>   new line character into the string by typing that actual character,
>   rather than using the Java escape sequence (\n).  So, you would want
>   to do something like this:
>
> ```
> #set( $new = "
> " )
> $foo.replaceAll( "$new", "$new * " )
> ```

in your case:

```
 #set( $new = "
 " )
<p>$myobject.description.replaceAll( "$new","<br/>")</p>
```